# How to align the first line of a paragraph center to an image. And the other lines and the first line are the same indentation?

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a paragraph. I want to 'css' the image is on the left and the paragraph on the right. And the first line of the paragraph has to display center to the image. And the other lines have to indent that is the same to the first line.

Can CSS do that? I hope you can teach me the way to achieve that.

Thank you in advanced!

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="parent">
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
  <div class="child">
 The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
img { 
   display: inline;
}
.child {
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qn4bh8ht/

DON'T WORK AT ALL. :(

Comment: I see many different solutions with different results and you are saying none of them is good, can you please add a mock up of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try these: [JsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn4bh8ht/1/).

I use `display: table` for the `.parent` class then `table-cell` for the children + `vertical-align: top` on the `.child` class.

```
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.parent > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I just want the first line is align center to the image. This doesn't work. Thanks for your reply, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Have an empyt `span` in the begining of para and set `width:45%`

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
  <div class="child"><span class="first-line">&nbsp;</span>
 <span> The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.first-line:{
  display:inline-block;
  width:45%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding to do that, also tag img is not a class, in the css file remove the "." before img.

```css
img { 
   float:left;
}
.child {
  padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
  <div class="child">
 The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font. 
  </div>
</div>
```